# On Azure Databricks how can I tell which blob store is mounted

Tags: azure, mount, databricks, blobstorage

I have inherited a notebook which writes to a mounted Azure blob storage, using syntax:

```
instrumentDf.write.json('/mnt/blobdata/cosmosdata/instrumentjson')
```

How can I find the name of the Azure blob storage it has written to ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use for this purpose:

```
dbutils.fs.mounts()
```

This lists the mountpoints and the source.